# How to show windows scan dialoge like bellow and transfer imag from it

Tags: wia

i want to show and use this dialoge
[windows scan dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56JRB.png)
not this

which is produced by this pice of code
img1 = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent, WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality, WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, True, True, False)

i googled for it but no help

Comment: i think i have to code it
the core idea is  pointoscreen and pointclient , croping the bitmap we scaneed